# Rails socialization follow method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the ruby socialization gem to allow people to follow each other. I am using the follows? method to see if the current user follows that user. SO if he already follows the user he can unfollow that user.

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
          <div class="user">
            <h2>Name - username</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla accumsan enim aliquam, vestibulum orci sed, tincidunt massa. Suspendisse semper ex non egestas tristique. Praesent quis nulla at nunc commodo tincidunt in eget felis. Nunc nec metus non nunc vulputate euismod vel quis elit.</p>
            <% if current_user.follows?(user) %>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">unfollow</button>
            <%else%>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">follow</button>
            <%end%>
          </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>




 Showing /Users/jmurphy/RubymineProjects/sql-ss/app/views/socail_network/user_display/display.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `follows?' for #<Class:0x007fb6a85dfc80>
```

Comment: What's the class of `current_user` and does a `follows?` instance method exist for that class?

Comment: current user is a devise method that gets the current users information.

Comment: What is a devise method? Regardless, what is the class of its return value.

Comment: I am not sure what the class is. This is the project on github. https://github.com/jmurphy45/SN-SQL

Comment: Well you have to find out what class `current_user` is and if the `follows?` method is undefined for that class define that method. I'm guessing that you want the class of `current_user` to include a module that defines `follows?` or extend a class that defines `follows?`.

Comment: The current_user is a generated devise class used from the authentication framework. Using this gem for the follows functionality https://github.com/cmer/socialization , and devise for authentication https://github.com/plataformatec/devise .